# How to automatically generate unique id in SQL like UID12345678?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to automatically generate unique id with per-defined code attach to it.

ex:

```
UID12345678
CUSID5000
```

I tried `uniqueidentifier` data type but it generate a id which is not suitable for a user id.

Any one have suggestions?

Comment: what is pattern between UID12345678 and CUSID5000.First identify pattern of unique id then accordingly create UDF that will return unique id.

Comment: thnx @KumarHarsh, Do you have any link or resource to follow??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The only viable solution in my opinion is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   UserID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `tblUsers` without specifying values for `ID` or `UserID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblUsersCol1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `UserID` will contain values like `UID00000001`, `UID00000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

**Update:** the column `UserID` is **computed** - but it still **OF COURSE** has a **data type**, as a quick peek into the Object Explorer reveals:

[image]

Comment: first id has to be bigint.second how will 12345678 geenerated with your table like this UID0000000012345678 .
so it has to be UDF and format 0000... using replicate .

Comment: thax @marc_s, work without errors. :)

Another small issue can 00000000 generate randomly without incrementing??

Comment: @KumarHarsh - What do you think `UserID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED` does?

Comment: marc_s I have a problem. I can't create a foreign key in another table which is referring to UID column of User table because UID doesn't have a data type. How to overcome this?

Comment: @ElhamKohestani: see my update, ***OF COURSE*** it has a datatype !!

Comment: Thank you, got it. But I still have a problem since it is nullable I can't refer it to a foreign key. I tried to modify it but it says Property can not be modified. How can I modify it to prevent from null values?

Comment: What if I add 'not null' at the end of column during the table creation query ?

Comment: I tried to alter it but it says: Cannot alter column 'UID' because it is 'COMPUTED'.

Comment: @ElhamKohestani: you need to define it like this, if it has to be not nullable: `UserID AS ISNULL('UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8), '*') PERSISTED` - with the use of `ISNULL()`, you can make sure that it's never ever going to be null

Comment: @marc_s thank you. I already solved that by creating the table from scratch and adding a UNIQUE constraint on the column. Won't it cause any problem in the future?

Comment: @ElhamKohestani: no, since the `ID` is an identity, that in itself is unique, so any computed column based on that value will be unique, too

Comment: Thank you @marc_s could you answer my question, please?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298886/how-to-calculate-the-custom-id-for-a-row-which-has-not-been-inserted-yet

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    UserID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

[image: marc_s's Answer Snap]

marc_s's Answer Snap

Comment: I have not tried something like that in mysql. But you can ask it from the genius @marc_s

Comment: @MohammedHousseynTaleb: sorry, I don't know MySQL well enough to tell you whether it supports this kind of thing.... but **YOU** can consult the **MySQL documentation** and see if it does!

Answer (score 3):

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

-- Creating a table using NEWID for uniqueidentifier data type.

```
CREATE TABLE cust  
(  
 CustomerID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL  
   DEFAULT newid(),  
 Company varchar(30) NOT NULL,  
 ContactName varchar(60) NOT NULL,   
 Address varchar(30) NOT NULL,   
 City varchar(30) NOT NULL,  
 StateProvince varchar(10) NULL,  
 PostalCode varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
 CountryRegion varchar(20) NOT NULL,   
 Telephone varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
 Fax varchar(15) NULL  
);  
GO  
-- Inserting 5 rows into cust table.  
INSERT cust  
(CustomerID, Company, ContactName, Address, City, StateProvince,   
 PostalCode, CountryRegion, Telephone, Fax)  
VALUES  
 (NEWID(), 'Wartian Herkku', 'Pirkko Koskitalo', 'Torikatu 38', 'Oulu', NULL,  
 '90110', 'Finland', '981-443655', '981-443655')  
,(NEWID(), 'Wellington Importadora', 'Paula Parente', 'Rua do Mercado, 12', 'Resende', 'SP',  
 '08737-363', 'Brasil', '(14) 555-8122', '')  
,(NEWID(), 'Cactus Comidas para Ilevar', 'Patricio Simpson', 'Cerrito 333', 'Buenos Aires', NULL,   
 '1010', 'Argentina', '(1) 135-5555', '(1) 135-4892')  
,(NEWID(), 'Ernst Handel', 'Roland Mendel', 'Kirchgasse 6', 'Graz', NULL,  
 '8010', 'Austria', '7675-3425', '7675-3426')  
,(NEWID(), 'Maison Dewey', 'Catherine Dewey', 'Rue Joseph-Bens 532', 'Bruxelles', NULL,  
 'B-1180', 'Belgium', '(02) 201 24 67', '(02) 201 24 68');  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Table Creating

```
create table emp(eno int identity(100001,1),ename varchar(50))
```

Values inserting

```
insert into emp(ename)values('narendra'),('ajay'),('anil'),('raju')
```

Select Table

```
select * from emp
```

Output

```
eno     ename
100001  narendra
100002  rama
100003  ajay
100004  anil
100005  raju
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'newid()' method unique id generate for per record.

```cs
AddColumn("dbo.Foo", "Key", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 250, defaultValueSql: "newid()"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the id **manually** you can use,

**[PadLeft()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)** or **[String.Format()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)** method.

```
string id;
char x='0';
id=id.PadLeft(6, x);
//Six character string id with left 0s e.g 000012

int id;
id=String.Format("{0:000000}",id);
//Integer length of 6 with the id. e.g 000012
```

Then you can append this with UID.