# Is there a way that a column in MYSQL table generate a formatted UID?

Tags: mysql, sql, identity, auto-generate

Is there a way that a column in MYSQL table generate a formatted UID like :

DNR00001/16
DNR00002/16
DNR00003/16

Where :

'DNR' a varchar

'00001' is the varchar(5) of the auto-incremented id

'/' is a separator

'16' is the year

I got inspired by this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674282/how-to-automatically-generate-unique-id-in-sql-like-uid12345678)

Thanks

Comment: You could use a trigger to build that for you, but you can't have a non-numeric auto-generated ID like that, the way a normal auto_increment works.

Comment: i know about triggers and auto-incremented ID but are not options on my case

Comment: What's your plan for the hundred thousandth record?

Comment: i will reset the auto increment because in one year i have about 10000 entry in the population then i must restart from 0 in the next year

Comment: and also i m using another primary key unlimited this is only a secondary key for clients

Comment: and i have only one subscribe for one client in all his life