# How to generate a unique transaction id in a shopping cart using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, uniqueidentifier

I'm new in PostgreSQL and a little bit confused.

I want to automatically generate unique transaction id with predefined code and attach to it inside the table.

like :

> TRX201909260001

The pattern should be: `'TRX'` + (yyyy/mm/dd) + (random number)

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674282/how-to-automatically-generate-unique-id-in-sql-like-uid12345678) that shows me how to do it like I want, but it is about SQL Server.

Comment: Will [UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html)s do?

Comment: Thanks! i already tried it but it generate total unique number. i want some semi-unique like
TRX - (yyyy/mm/dd) - (random number) . so it will be like : TRX201908271319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE unique_id_seq;
```

Then you can generate the unique identifier with the following SQL expression:

```
'TRX' || to_char(current_date, 'YYYYMMDD') || lpad(nextval('unique_id_seq'), 18, '0')
```

That will not be a random value, and the prefix is not necessary to guarantee uniqueness, but it should fullfill the requirement.

Comment: it should be an easy task, but since I'm newbie here, I'm still confused.. What should I write in pgAdmin? this is my current query:

CREATE TABLE master_transaction(
 trx_id  uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
 invoice ,
 number_plate VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 ts TIMESTAMP ,
 length real,
 width real
 );
 
INSERT INTO master_transaction (invoice, number_plate, ts, length, width)
VALUES 
.
I want that "trx..." in my invoice column

Comment: Right - use the expression as `DEFAULT` value for the column.