# SQL: Oracle 19c unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I'm currently trying to understand how to generate Unique ID in SQL like HID0014. I can't seem to find any resources or documentation to help with this problem except answer in:

[How to automatically generate unique id in SQL like UID12345678?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674282/how-to-automatically-generate-unique-id-in-sql-like-uid12345678)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblUsers
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    UserID AS 'UID' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(8)), 8) PERSISTED, 
    [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

I have tried using it in my Oracle 19c SQL plus to generate a table but I am getting errors. Can someone explain if I am using the wrong syntax? Or the code provided above is invalid for Oracle 19c.

Comment: Don't expect that SQL Server solution to work on Oracle.

Comment: Seems, the above code is valid for MS SQL Server

Comment: Oracle calls these _virtual columns_.

Comment: do I only need to study oracle virtual columns to get similar results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an identity column and a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  id     INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
         NOT NULL
         CONSTRAINT table_name__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  userid VARCHAR2(11)
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
           CAST('UID' || TO_CHAR(id, 'FM00000000') AS VARCHAR2(11))
         ),
  name   VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (name)
SELECT 'Alice' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beryl' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Carol' FROM DUAL;

SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

> | ID | USERID | NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | UID00000001 | Alice |
> | 2 | UID00000002 | Beryl |
> | 3 | UID00000003 | Carol |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=99a3c10b0b83935769330878aa763fe3)*